# Pac-Man 99: What do the different strategies do?

Tags: pac-man-99

Pac-Man 99 recently came out and as usual with those retro games with battle royale style gameplay offered for free on Nintendo's online subscription service, they don't really care to explain how certain elements of the gameplay work. One of those elements is the different "strategies" you can employ.

Unlike Tetris 99 and Super Mario Bros. 35, you can't manually target individual players. Instead, in addition to the usual targeting system, you also have a "style" system. These two systems are called "strategies" in the game.

**Style**

- Standard
- Stronger
- Speed
- Train

**Target**

- Random
- Hunter
- Knockout
- Counter

Some of these are obvious, like the random targeting one, but what about the rest? How does style work and when does it come into effect? Does the target "Hunter" mean I target players who are under the effects of a power pellet?

Answer (score 1):

According to Gamepur, each style is applied every time you eat the power pellet. Here are all the style effects:

> **Faster** – Your Pac-Man’s movement speed is doubled. However, your attack is lowered by 75%
> **Stronger** – Whenever you consume a ghost, two transparent Pac-Man will be sent to an opponent’s board, but your power pellet time is lowered by three seconds
> **Train** – Whenever you touch a ghost, they double, but it also spawns one of the transparent Pac-Man to your board
> **Standard** – There are no benefits or disadvantages to this choice

As for the strategies (Targets), I'm not really sure. I *do* know that random is obviously random, and I also know that knockout is to target players that are close to losing.

Also, you can check out the entire page here: [Gamepur.com](https://www.gamepur.com/guides/all-power-ups-and-how-they-work-in-pac-man-99)